# Facebook not recoginising open graph tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

My object page looks like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US"
  xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# cliprin: 
              http://ogp.me/ns/apps/cliprin#">

<meta property="fb:app_id" content="143944345745133" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="cliprin:product" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="https://itsourstudio.com/" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="LED Ice Cubes (Set Of 4)" /> 
<meta property="og:sitename"  content="Its Our Studio" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  
  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" /> 
<meta property="og:description"  content="Blah Blah Blah" /> 

</head>
</html>
```

The JSLink Debugger of the page as shown by the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fclipr.in%2Foutput%2Ffbproduct.php) shows that

```
of:type is website
```

and gives following warnings:

```
Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed
 Inferred Property: The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
 Inferred Property: The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
 Inferred Property: The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
 Inferred Property: The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
 Tiny og:image: All the images referenced by og:image must be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the minimum specification.
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook will follow the link in `og:url` tag (the *Canonical URL*) and you don't have the right OG meta tags there. It's similar if you debug `https://itsourstudio.com/` directly, see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=https://itsourstudio.com).

The **Redirect Path** section is clearly stating that:

> Final URL is in **bold** (this is the URL we tried to extract metadata
>   from).